# How to use strstr() php

Tags: php

I want to cut text in array but I have no idea to cut this
I try strstr() but it not true.

I try

```
$ff='';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
   $ff .= $row['fav'] . ",";

}
 if( strpos( $ff, "_" )) {

        $text = strstr($ff, '_');
        echo $text;

        }
```

> $ff ='A_0089,A_5677,B_4387,A_B_5566,'

I want output show

> 0089,5677,4387,B_5566,

Comment: Use `substr()`.

Comment: Or str_replace(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @JayBlanchard Can you show example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example, using `substr()` with `strpos()`:

```
$ff='A_0089,A_5677,B_4387,A_B_5566';
$items = explode(',', $ff);
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo substr($item, strpos($item, '_')) . "\n";
}
```

The above code returns:

```
_0089
_5677
_4387
_B_5566
```

You're better off not building a string, but building an array. The way you build the string you have a dangling comma, which you do not want.

```
$ff = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
   $ff[] = $row['fav'];

}
foreach($ff as $item) {
    echo substr($item, strpos($item, '_')) . "\n";
}
```

---

Based on your desire to keep the commas and create a string:

```
$ff='A_0089,A_5677,B_4387,A_B_5566,';
$items = explode(',', $ff);
foreach($items as $item) {
    $new[] =  substr($item, strpos($item, '_'));
}
$newFF = implode(',', $new);
echo $newFF;
```

returns:

```
_0089,_5677,_4387,_B_5566,
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you are looking for

```
<?php
function test_alter(&$item1)
{
    $pattern = '/^[A-Z]{1}[_]{1}/';
    $item1 =preg_replace($pattern,"",$item1);
}

$ff="A_0089,A_5677,B_4387,A_B_5566,";
$nff=explode(",",$ff);
array_walk($nff, 'test_alter');
echo implode(",",$nff);
?>
```